# Can I use a regular expression while matching an index of a key in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have created a key which matches a tag and uses their names as indices.

Is there a way to match regular expression in index of key while using it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explain more detail how you input data looks and what exactly you want to achieve with a regular expression match. You can of course use the XPath 2 functions like `tokenize` and `matches` both in your `match` pattern (e.g. `match="*[matches(local-name(), '^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}')]$"`) or your use expression (e.g. `use="tokenize(foo, '\s+')"`). The key values will be atomic values (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-key). When you call the `key` function, you can of course again use any XPath expression, including ones using regular expressions, to compute the key value(s) you pass to the function.